How to automate PDF Printing from Google Sheets to Google Drive
I would like to print a PDF automatically by just clicking an icon (I inserted an image and assigned a script) but I keep getting an error of 'Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: body{height:100%;margin:0;width:100%}@media (max-height:350px){.button{font-size:10px}.button-... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)'
Here's my script:
function downloadSheetAsPDF() {
  var filename = "Filename.pdf"; // Please set the filename here.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();

  // Creat PDF file as a temporary file and create URL for downloading.
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y0EFMawnXD6hO8w-vp0m5JiLpQ0wHJYEpHQfOtb2DuI/edit#gid=1644292308" + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(filename);
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  var dlUrl = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jhs7jYwf3LuDTRIN6X7rfGd_UOm9kR7f" + file.getId();

  // Open a dialog and run Javascript for downloading the file.
  var str = '<script>window.location.href="' + dlUrl + '"</script>';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Download PDF");
  file.setTrashed(true);

  // This is used for closing the dialog.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  var closeHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>google.script.host.close()</script>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(closeHtml, "Download PDF");
}

By clicking an icon I will be able to print the active cells into PDF and store it on google drive.

In your code your URL string is wrong. Its concatenation is wrong. Specifically, the URL hardcoded part should not be there. The 'dlUrl' is incorrect for the direct download link from Google Drive.
You can use this script.
  function downloadSheetAsPDF() {
  var filename = "Filename.pdf"; 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId;

  // Fetch the PDF as a binary large object file for the authentication
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  }).getBlob().setName(filename);

  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

  var dlUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();

  // Opening a dialog to download the file
  var str = '<script>window.location.href="' + dlUrl + '";google.script.host.close();</script>';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Download PDF");

  file.setTrashed(true);
}

